# Querying DB for users when not all given parameters are filled

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Sorry about the title being confusing it was hard to figure out how to word the question.

Currently I have a sqllite db with some users in it they have a first name, last name, dob, high school, and high school class. The db is connected to flask using sqlalchemy. What I'm wondering is for my search function I have 4 inputs and I want to have it so if an input isn't used then it won't be used in the search query. Say the person searches for the last name and high school I want it to search just using those parameters. I've tried doing this using a bunch of if statements but it seems messy there must be a better way. Below is the query that I use but it only works if all 4 are filled. Is there a better way than a bunch of if statements with different queries? I've looked around and haven't found anything.

```
userq=User.query.filter_by(first_name=fname_strip,last_name=lname_strip,hs_class=hs_class_strip).all()
```

Comment: Just omit the `kwargs` corresponding to the elements that you don't want to search by when calling `filter_by`

Comment: Is there anyway to have it not use kwargs that are set to none or ''?

Comment: Do not pass `kwargs` with unwanted args set to `''` or `None` - delete empty values instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so what I did was go through and make an if statement like you said but made them into different vars. Then check to see if they where none or not correct and if they were good then they queryied correctly if not then the queried for everything not null. Then changed them to be a set then did set intersection to see what was the same through all of them. Thank you for ionheart for helping me through this and providing the information this is the complete answer using his partial solution.

```
            userf=set()
            userl=set()
            userc=set()
            userh=set()
            if fname_strip!='':
                userf = User.query.filter_by(first_name=fname_strip).all()
                print(userf)
            else:
                userf = User.query.filter(User.first_name.isnot(None))
            if lname_strip!='':
                userl = User.query.filter_by(last_name=lname_strip).all()
                print(userl)
            else:
                userl = User.query.filter(User.last_name.isnot(None))
            try:
                int(hs_class_strip)
                userc = User.query.filter_by(hs_class=hs_class_strip).all()
                print(userc)
            except:
                userc = User.query.filter(User.hs_class.isnot(None))
            if hs_strip!='':
                userh = User.query.filter_by(hs=hs_strip).all()
                print(userh)
            else:
                userh = User.query.filter(User.hs.isnot(None))

            userq=[]
            common=set(userf) & set(userl) & set(userc) & set(userh)
            print(common)
```

Comment: glad to be of service!

Answer (score 1):

You can try if/else statements like the following:

```
q = User.query.filter_by(first_name=first_name)
if lname_strip:
    q = q.filter_by(last_name=lname_strip)
if hs_class_strip:
    q= q.filter_by(hs_class=hs_class_strip)

# Execute the query
q.all()
```

- Updated needs the q to be an assignment.

Comment: I did this and it doesn't seem to be filtering after the first name like if I have 2 people with the same first name but different years it won't filter between them.

Comment: You'll need to refine the search further by adding years in to the filter.  I'm assuming you have a year column in your model.

Comment: Year is hs_class_strip like even if they have different last names and I try to filter it will still return multiple entries

Comment: I updated the answer base on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517414/sqlalchemy-conditional-multiple-filters-on-dynamic-lazy-relationship

filter() returns a new query object, but you do not store it. Replace p with the result each time:

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the arguments to your search function as keyword arguments you can change the signature to accept kwargs and pass those on to the filter query

```
def search(**kwargs):
    userq = User.query.filter_by(**kwargs).all()
```

This way any arguments you don't specify when calling `search` will not be passed onto the query, for example calling `search(first_name='bob', last_name='fossil')` will only add first name and surname arguments to the query